# Foreign key constraint error with code first...working fine with model-first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to create a school base applicaiton using code first approach but getting "Foreign key constraint error" on my Result table...tried making the same applicaiton with model-first approach and its working fine...

this is the error im getting

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.Semestersubjects_dbo.Semesters_semesterId' on table
>   'Semestersubjects' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify
>   ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN
>   KEY constraints.
>
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

This is what my context class look like

```
 public class student
    {
        public student()
        {
            this.SemesterStudents = new HashSet<Semesterstudent>();
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Semesterstudent> SemesterStudents { get; set; }
    }
    public class Semester
    {
        public Semester()
        {
            this.SemesterStudents = new HashSet<Semesterstudent>();
            this.Semestersubjects = new HashSet<Semestersubject>();
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ICollection<Semesterstudent> SemesterStudents { get; set; }
        ICollection<Semestersubject> Semestersubjects { get; set; }
    }
    public class Semesterstudent
    {
        public Semesterstudent()
        {
            this.Results = new HashSet<Result>();
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int studentId { get; set; }
        public int semesterId { get; set; }
        public virtual student students { get; set; }
        public virtual Semester semesters { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
    public class Semestersubject
    {
        public Semestersubject()
        {
            this.Results = new HashSet<Result>();
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int semesterId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public virtual Semester semesters { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
    }
    public class Result
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int SemesterstudentId { get; set; }
        public int SemestersubjectId { get; set; }
        public int Marks { get; set; }
        public virtual Semesterstudent SemesterStudents { get; set; }
        public virtual Semestersubject SemesterSubjects { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show us your OnModelCreating method.

Comment: im not using onModelCreating method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments have stated, you should show your `OnModelCreating` method for better answers. But to decipher the error message for you, it's saying there's a problem with the delete action - that it is cascading (eg. if you delete one entity it also deletes the related entities). The problem with this, is that if you were to delete a `SemesterSubject` the cascade would then also delete the `Semester` which would then (assuming the `Semester` delete action is also cascade) also delete the related `SemesterSubjects` which to quote the error `may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths`

Again if you show your `OnModelCreating` you will get better information on how to fix the error, but the short answer is to configure your foreign key to change the `OnDelete` behaviour so this doesn't cascade eg. (may be different depending on which version you are using etc.)

```
builder.Entity<SemesterSubject>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(e => e.semesters)
        .WithMany(e => e.Semestersubjects)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.semesterId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
});
```